# LWC with Leaflet JS >> How to access variables or functions outside of L.geoJson

Tags: lightning-web-components, map, leaflet.js

I'm POC'ing using Leaflet.JS to render maps within a Lightning Community.  On initial testing it out it looks good.  One aspect I've noted and I'm trying to figure out is that within the JS L.geoJson(this.geoJSON,{..... which sets up my map I can't seem to access variables in my lWC outside of this function.  I noted the following which isn't LWC specific https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611611/call-a-function-outside-oneachfeature-leaflet  but on trying a similar approach it did not work. I was thinking maybe the behaviour is different in LWC. For example in layer.click in the following I tried a couple of approaches

```
import { LightningElement, track,api } from 'lwc';
import leafletUtils from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/leafletUtils';
import leaflet from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Leaflet';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import getJSONFromResource from '@salesforce/apex/LeafletExample.getJSON';

export default class GeoJSONLeaflet extends LightningElement {
    geoJSON;

    lVariable;

    librariesInitialised = false;
    mapAppplied = false;

    au = [
        [-10,110],
        [-44,155]
    ];
    allowedCountries = {};

    countryMapKey = {};

    renderedCallback(){
        if (this.librariesInitialised) {
            return;
        }
        this.librariesInitialised = true;

        Promise.all([
            //loadScript(this, jQueryMin),
            loadScript(this, leaflet + '/leaflet.js'),
            loadStyle(this, leaflet + '/leaflet.css')
        ])
            .then(() => {
                this.getJSON();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error loading D3',
                        message: error.message,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            });
    }

    setupMap(){
        console.log('in setupMap 1');
        var myCustomStyle = {
            stroke: false,
            fill: true,
            fillColor: '#fff',
            fillOpacity: 1
        }

        const mapRoot = this.template.querySelector(".map-root");
        var map = L.map(mapRoot).setView([39.74739, -105], 4);

        L.geoJson(this.geoJSON,{
            clickable:true,
            style: function(item){
                if(item.properties.type == 'stateline'){
                    return {
                        fill:false,
                        stroke:true,
                        color:'#EAEAEA',
                        weight:2
                    }
                } if(item.geometry.type == 'Point'){
                    if(item.properties.importance > 1){
                        return {
                            fill:false,
                            stroke:false
                        }
                    }

                    return {
                        fill:true,
                        fillOpacity:1,
                        stroke:false,
                        fillColor:"#aaa",
                        radius: 2 / item.properties.importance
                    }

                } else {
                    return {
                        fillColor:'#fff',
                        fillOpacity:1,
                        fill:true,
                        color:'#eeeeff',
                        weight:1
                    }
                }
            },
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.circleMarker(latlng)
                    .bindLabel(feature.properties.name,{
                        noHide:true
                    });
            },
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                var name = feature.properties.name;
                function ctxFillColor(){
                    return '#ffddff';
                }

                layer.on('click', this.outsideTest(event));
                //layer.on('click', this.outsideTest);
                /*
                layer.on('click',function(){
                    layer.setStyle({
                        fillColor: ctxFillColor()
                    });
                });
                */
            
            }
        }).addTo(map)
    }

    
    outsideTest(e) {
        console.log('Made it to here');
        var layer = e.target;
        var flag = layer.feature.properties.iso_a2.toLowerCase();
        Swal.fire({
            title: "You have selected",
            icon: "info",
            html: '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-'+flag+'"></span>'
        })
    }



    getJSON() {
        getJSONFromResource()
            .then(result => {
                //console.log('WHAT result ' + result);
                //this.geoJSON = $.parseJSON(result);
                this.geoJSON = JSON.parse(result);
                this.setupMap();

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('error', error);
                this.error = error;
            });
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can access variables and functions outside of the Leaflet code? The map works great if just using the map on the LWC but I need to pass variables to and from the map and therefore this brings about my questions.

Thanks in advance for any tips on this. Appreciated as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the classic functions to arrow functions, so that they get access to the `this` of the lightning web component. See the below examples.

```
// ...    
L.geoJson(this.geoJSON,{
    clickable:true,
    style: (item) => {
        if(item.properties.type == 'stateline'){
            return {
                fill:false,
                stroke:true,
                color:'#EAEAEA',
                weight:2
            }
        } if(item.geometry.type == 'Point'){
            if(item.properties.importance > 1){
                return {
                    fill:false,
                    stroke:false
                }
            }

            return {
                fill:true,
                fillOpacity:1,
                stroke:false,
                fillColor:"#aaa",
                radius: 2 / item.properties.importance
            }

        } else {
            return {
                fillColor:'#fff',
                fillOpacity:1,
                fill:true,
                color:'#eeeeff',
                weight:1
            }
        }
    },
    pointToLayer: (feature, latlng) => {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng)
            .bindLabel(feature.properties.name,{
                noHide:true
            });
    },
    onEachFeature: (feature, layer) => {
        var name = feature.properties.name;
        function ctxFillColor(){
            return '#ffddff';
        }

        layer.on('click', this.outsideTest(event));
        //layer.on('click', this.outsideTest);
        /*
        layer.on('click',function(){
            layer.setStyle({
                fillColor: ctxFillColor()
            });
        });
        */
    
    }
}).addTo(map)
//...
```

Comment: Thank you @Rahul Gawale. I do recall sfrcfox providing a useful link for me to view on arrow functions previously also. I must revisit & try to understand them fully.  Thanks again. This has worked for my requirement.